# Как удалить из текстового файла все строки по шаблону?

Tags: delphi

Нужно удалить из файла все строки в которых присутствует текст из `Edit1.Text`.

Необходимое условие - без загрузки всего файла в память, а чтением построчно (т.к. файл очень большой, 200мб+).

Пробовала так и результат ноль. Помогите подправить код.

```
var
  i,j: integer;
  f: textfile;
  s: string;
begin


    While not (Eof(f)) and (Pos(edit1.Text, s)=0) do begin // пока не дойдём до конца и edit1
      for i := 1 to length(s) do
      Begin
        if pos(edit1.Text,s)>0 then begin
          delete(S, pos(#13, s) , length(s));
          showmessage(edit1.Text+' удален!');
        end
        else write(f,s);
      end;
    end;

  CloseFile(f); // закрыть файлы
end;
```

Comment: а где у тебя чтение строки из файла ?

Comment: Уже решила вопрос. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы точно не забыли `begin` после `if OpenDialog1.Execute then` ?

Comment: Тоже это сделала, спасибо за подсказку.

Answer (score 2):

Решила таким способом:

```
Reset(ft);
AssignFile(ft2, fn2);
Rewrite(ft2);
Append(ft2);
while not Eof(ft) do
begin
    Readln(ft, s);
    if Pos(Edit1.Text, s) = 0 then
        WriteLn(ft2, s);
end;
CloseFile(ft);
CloseFile(ft2);
```

Comment: Оставьте что-нибудь одно - `Rewrite(ft2);` или `Append(ft2);`.

Comment: Тоже дельный совет. Воспользовалась им. Спасибо.