# Удаление от начала / от конца строки / Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi

Сделала вот так. И файлы размером в 500 мегабайт не обрабатывает - нехватка памяти):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var t:TStringList;
    s: string;
    k,n,i: integer;
begin
n:=strtoint(Edit1.Text);//удалить в начале
k:=strtoint(Edit2.Text);//удалить в конце
t:=TStringList.Create;
t.LoadFromFile('1.txt');//файл в папке с программой
for i:=0 to t.Count-1 do
 begin
  s:=t[i];
  if k>=length(s) then s:=''
  else delete(s,length(s)-k+1,k);
  if n>=length(s) then s:=''
  else delete(s,1,n);
  t[i]:=s;
 end;
t.SaveToFile('2.txt');
t.Free;
ShowMessage('Файл 1.txt преобразован и записан в файл 2.txt')
end;
```

**Как переделать через:**

> AsssignFile, Reset/Rewrite, CloseFile

То есть читать по строкам а не загружать в память.

**>>> Делаю так (В чем моя ошибка ?): <<<**

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
f1,f2:TextFile;
s:string;
k,n,i: integer;
begin
 if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
AssignFile(f1,OpenDialog1.FileName);
AssignFile(f2,ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName)+'\out.txt');
{$i-}
Reset(f1); Rewrite(f2);
 begin
  s:=f1[i];
  if k>=length(s) then s:=''
  else delete(s,length(s)-k+1,k);
  if n>=length(s) then s:=''
  else delete(s,1,n);
  f2[i]:=s;
 end;
CloseFile(f1);
CloseFile(f2);
end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Татьяна, мы с интересом следим за Вашими действиями на StackOverflow, радуемся Вашим успехам, переживаем неудачи. За последнее время Вы задали уже с полдюжины вопросов, ответ на которые абсолютно одинаков.  Вот один из них https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/790226 с Вашим собственным ответом. Что с Вами, Татьяна?

Comment: Во первых спасибо от чистого сердца. Со мной все нормально, уже прошла путь обучения. Благодаря всеобщей критике. В этом вопросе уже два часа сражаюсь с кодом. И пока что с 10 попытки не получается переделать.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос Ваш код с построчным чтением/записью, и Вам помогут найти ошибку.

Comment: Одну минутку. Сейчас сделаю.

Comment: Igor 9, Добавила к основному вопросу свой код. Как Вы и сказали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while not EOF(f1) do // вместо for ... в случае с TStringList
begin
  ReadLn(f1, s); // вместо s:=f1[i];
  ...  
  WriteLn(f2, s); // вместо f2[i]:=s;
end;
```

> ... очищает полностью. В чем еще может быть ошибка

Еще ошибка в том, что Вы не присваиваете значение `n`. В этой неинициализированной локальной переменной находится мусор, соответствующий какому-то большому целому числу. Поэтому условие `n>=length(s)` всегда истинно, и строка всегда очищается.

Переменнoй `k` Ваш код тоже не присваивает никакого значения.

Comment: Так сделала, работает, но не обрезает файл ?. А очищает полностью. В чем еще может быть ошибка ?. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Присвоила условие n:=strtoint(Edit1.Text);//удалить в начале
k:=strtoint(Edit2.Text);//удалить в конце. И теперь обрезает, но оставляет только первую строку а остальные строки удаляет. В чем тут ошибка ?

Comment: @Татьяна Добавил цикл `while` в ответ.

Comment: Igor, Спасибо большое - все получилось с вашей помощью! Сейчас напишу ответ в этот вопрос.

Comment: @Татьяна На этом ресурсе считается хорошим тоном "принимать" правильный ответ на вопрос щелчком по знаку "галочка" слева от ответа.

Comment: Сделал, извините что сразу не нажала. Просто от впечатление что получилось. Огромное спасибо.

Comment: @Татьяна На здоровье. Успехов!

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря пользователь **Igor** получилось. Ответ на вопрос:

```
n:=strtoint(Edit1.Text); //удалить в начале
k:=strtoint(Edit2.Text); //удалить в конце

AssignFile(f1,OpenDialog1.FileName);
AssignFile(f2,ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName)+'\out.txt');
{$i-}
Reset(f1); Rewrite(f2);
while not Eof(f1) do begin
  ReadLn(f1, s);
  if k>=length(s) then s:='2'
  else delete(s,length(s)-k+1,k);
  if n>=length(s) then s:='2'
  else delete(s,1,n);
  WriteLn(f2, s);
 end;
```

Comment: `{$i-}` лучше уберите. О происходящих ошибках лучше сразу узнавать в виде исключения.